# Link Bullet Physics using CMake

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I'm new in using CMake. Now I'm trying to link Bullet to my demo.

Bullet's Wiki says that, with gcc I need to do something like this

```
gcc myprogram.cpp -lGL -lGLU -I ./bullet/ ./bullet/BulletDynamics/libBulletDynamics.a ./bullet/BulletCollision/libBulletCollision.a ./bullet/LinearMath/libLinearMath.a
```

My MakeFileLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Hello)

include_directories(bullet/src)

add_executable(Hello main.cpp)
```

I was trying to use target_link_libraries but cmake is just adding -l as prefix.

What is proper way to link these libs?

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to use `target_link_libraries` indeed. Smth like this:

```
add_executable(Hello main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Hello
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bullet/BulletDynamics/libBulletDynamics.a
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bullet/BulletCollision/libBulletCollision.a
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bullet/LinearMath/libLinearMath.a
    -lGL -lGLU)
```

(assuming that you have already built/installed all Bullet libraries in the source directory of your project. You may use absolute paths here if you wish). Also you may run `make VERBOSE=1` to see which commands are actually issued during the compilation.

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. Use `pkg_check_modules(BULLET bullet>=2.82)`.

Comment: `pkg_check_modules` won't find a library located within project's source tree. Since the macro is based on `pkg-config` functionality it's completely useless w/o correctly formed `<library>.pc` file, describing actual location of the library artifacts. I doubt that Sekhmet had one when he asked for help.